# Chrome - Inspect Element - Finding file with specific text in it?

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, developer-tools

I am trying to find the location of a "click here to try your search again" phrase by using the "Inspect Element" tool in Chrome's Developer mode. When I find it in Developer tools, it states that it should be located in my Support.php file - however it is not. I'm assuming it is located deep down in some include of some kind, inside of a random PHP file. How do I go about finding out exactly WHICH file the exact words in that phrase are located in?

Sorry if its a ridiculous question, just can't figure it out.

Comment: Chrome can't access to any php file. It just can see generated html, js and css pages. So you must use the search option of your IDE to looking for a text in php file.

Comment: are you running on Linux or MacOSx? if yes, issue> grep -i -r "click here to try your search again" * in the directory where the files live.

Answer (score 0):

are you running on Linux or MacOSx? if yes, issue> `grep -i -r "click here to try your search again" *` in the directory where the files live or `sudo grep -i -r "click here to try your search again" *`

or if you're on windows you can use

```
http://www.wingrep.com
http://www.wingrep.com/resources/binaries/WindowsGrep23.exe
```